# Uninstalling opencv yet pkg-config still shows the version number

Tags: opencv, pkg-config

I've searched similar topics but didn't solved my problem.
I've uninstalled opencv-3.2.0 from source using:

```
sudo make uninstall
```

and I want to install opencv-3.3.1 but before i do that i wanted to make sure the previous version in completely gone.
so i ran:

```
pkg-config --modversion opencv
```

and it returns

```
3.2.0
```

how do i make the system forget about 3.2.0 version, and move on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pkg-config` uses a bunch of `.pc` files to find information about the installed packages. When using `pkg-config`, it simply prints section of the relevant file.

These files are usually located in `/usr/lib/pkgconfig` or `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`. Additional paths can be specified using the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variables.

My point is that `pkg-config` has no idea about what libraries are installed or not. It simply outputs the content of the `.pc` file.

Most likely what happened is that `make uninstall` forgot about `opencv.pc`.

You can more reliably check if you still have some of OpenCV installed by looking in your system. OpenCV should come with an include directory in `/usr/include/opencv` or `/usr/local/include/opencv` and some libraries `/usr/lib/libopencv_*` or `/usr/local/lib/libopencv_*`.

Comment: thank you very much, `opencv.pc` was in `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`, i've manually removed some of `libopencv*` and didn't check about `opencv*`, thanks again